# Twig for loop ends after first run for no reason

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the following issue which I can't solve:

First a variable is set and I clone it to run the a loop inside the original loop (trying to achive some parent child listing):

```
{% set _sub_currentPageResults = paginator.currentPageResults %}
{{ dump(_sub_currentPageResults) }}
{% for item in paginator.currentPageResults %}

<b>ITEM: {{ item.id }}</b></br>

{% if item.isParent %}
```

Case 1 (testing), sub loop is working fine, main loop continues:

```
{% for sub_item in [{'id': 1}, {'id' : 2}, {'id' : 3}, {'id' : 4}, {'id' : 5}, {'id' : 6}, {'id' : 7}, {'id' : 8}, {'id' : 9}, {'id' : 10}, {'id' : 11}, {'id' : 12}, {'id' : 13}, {'id' : 14}] %}
[{{ sub_item.id }}]
{% endfor %}</br>
```

[rendered result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZcEI.png)

Case 2 (normal), sub loop is working fine, main loop stops after first run:

```
{% for sub_item in _sub_currentPageResults %}
[{{ sub_item.id }}]
{% endfor %}</br>
```

[rendered result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkKZy.png)

Its exactly the same data as used in the main loop that works fine in test case.
Am I missing something?

File: [list_product.html.twig](https://gist.github.com/mrvnklm/486543a4c3dcea32a90f91e3b4a0131c)
using
[EasyAdminBundle](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle)

Comment: What happens if you do: `{% for sub_item in paginator.currentPageResults %}
[{{ sub_item.id }}]
{% endfor %}</br>` ?

Comment: same issue, actually I tried that first, but cloned the data for testing

Comment: Maybe you have an issue with your paginator? You could post the code for the pagination as well.

Comment: I'm using the EasyAdminBundle, I added a gist to my question. I didn't do anything with the paginator.
There might be one thing: as the object is type of _arrayiterator_, the set method could just reference and once the loop is completed, the main loop is too?

Comment: trying the following ended up working:

`{% for i in 0..paginator.currentPageResults|length-1 %}
{% set item = paginator.currentPageResults[i] %}
<b>ITEM: {{ item.id }}</b></br>`

thats about alright for me, but if there is a better solution (which I'm sure it is), please let me know

Comment: what about: `{% for item in paginator.currentPageResults %}` and within that loop `{% for subitem in item %}` ?

Comment: I guess that would not return the data I need to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main loop you are looping though `paginator.currentPageResults`.

In the sub loop you are doing the same because of this.
`{% set _sub_currentPageResults = paginator.currentPageResults %}`

Since this is an iterator, you "exhaust" it in your subloop.
You should cast it to an array.

EDIT: This behavior can be checked through this example: https://repl.it/repls/RustyNoxiousFiletype

Comment: Alright, so I wasn't too wrong. Thanks a lot. Is there a way to cast it to array in twig?

Comment: I don't think so. You will have to create an extension. I recommend creating an universal extension for rarely used php functions, like `|phpfunc('iterator_to_array', [paginator.currentPageResults])`, and using `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: This behavior can be checked through this example: https://repl.it/repls/RustyNoxiousFiletype